# Enable dead keys in Gnome login screen (Gnome 3.30.2)

Tags: debian, kali-linux, keyboard, gnome3, gdm3

I am running Kali Linux 2019 with Gnome 3.30.2 on a somewhat older Lenovo ThinkPad s540 and I am really enjoying modern Gnome. I do have a problem though;

I'm located in the Netherlands, so the keyboard layout that is common over here is US International with Dead Keys. In `/etc/default/keyboard`:

```
XKBLAYOUT=us
XKBVARIANT=intl
BACKSPACE=guess
```

I have also made sure that the right keyboard layout is set in Gnome Settings. For this, I had to add English (US, intl with Dead Keys).

Which is perfectly fine. I can use my keyboard layout throughout a Gnome session and dead keys are functioning as well. i.e. `<Shift+6>,<U>` results in Û. The problem comes around when I start the laptop and I get the Gnome login screen.

Dead keys are not recognized at all in there, they do not even work as regular keys. `<Shift+6>` results in nothing (either when followed by a space or supported character yields no output).

I have been trying to look for ways to enable dead keys in the login screen, however I found no results. All accessibility options are turned off with the exception of the On-Screen keyboard so that I am able to 'type' the special characters through that.

How can I enable dead keys in gnome-login?